# Getting the value from python script into a powershell script

Tags: python, powershell

I have python script which creates a ticket.
I need to invoke the python script from within powershell script and
get the ticketnumber(12 digit long).

Approach#1:

I tried to use the exit(ticket_number) to get this done.It worked well as long as the number is not very large.

Ex.

- exit(12345) from python translates to $LASTEXITCODE=12345  #good
- exit(123456789123) from python translates to $LASTEXITCODE=-1 #not sure what is going wrong here

```
    dummy.py
    --------
    print("hello")
    exit(123456789123)
       
    sample.ps1
    ----------
    python dummy.py
    Write-Host($LASTEXITCODE)
```

Approach#2:

Use of env variable

```
dummy.py
--------
import os
os.environ["TICKETNUMBER"] = "123456789123"
exit(0)

sample.ps1
----------
Get-ChildItem -Path Env:TEMP # good - able to get value
Get-ChildItem -Path Env:TICKETNUMBER # - error - ItemNotFoundException
```

So, I would like to know what is going wrong in each of the approaches.
Are there any better approaches to get this done - Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use exit codes to output a value, this simply isn't what they're meant to do. You can read more about exit codes here: https://shapeshed.com/unix-exit-codes/#what-is-an-exit-code-in-the-unix-or-linux-shell

Environment variables only work for passing around values when you're passing them to children. If you spawn a new process, said process will inherit the environment variables in scope of your current session. However, you can't change the environment variables of the parent (your session) from the child (the python runtime). Thus, in Powershell, your "TICKETNUMBER" environment variable is out of scope.

First of all let me say that there are many different ways to go about solving this. The solution that requires the least amount of work on your part would be to output to **stdout**, which allows you to output values for consumption by other processes. You can do this with `print` in python. You already did this but likely ran into issues due to your use of exit codes.

In Powershell, you can accept this input via the pipeline. There are a lot of ways to go about this, but in your example the `$input` variable will work.

```
dummy.py
--------
print("123123123")

sample.ps1
--------
Get-ChildItem -Path $input
```

You can then run `py dummy.py | ./sample.ps1`, which will return the directory listing of "./123123123".